# How to assign value for javascript variable from MVC asp.net controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Again stupid question 
struggling to assign a value for a javascript variable from controller ?

what is the proper way to assign value to a variable 
below line of code is failing .. Please advice

```
  var tenmp= '<%= Model.Temp%>';
```

Comment: This code should work properly.

Comment: This looks fine, are you getting some error or is tenmp empty?

Comment: The code looks good. Have you checked the HTML source to see if the value is embedded? Could you provide more details on the problem? Is it because you have a typo on your 'tenmp' var?

Answer (score 4):

I've just tried the same as you and it works fine.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var a = '<%=Model.userName %>';

    alert(a);
</script>
```

In my controller I have the following;

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    LoginFormViewModel loginFVM = new LoginFormViewModel();
    loginFVM.userName = "slappy";

    return View(loginFVM);
}
```

All the above assumes that you are trying to get a model value into javascript from your view.

Also, ensure that your view is inheriting from your model else it'd have no idea what temp is.

Hope this is of help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write, use `<%` in controllers.

You would probably be using it in aspx/ ascx pages, something like

```
<input type="hidden" class="pnum" value="<%=PageNum%>" />
```

if you are using in aspx or ascx page then directly use

```
<% var tenmp= Model.Temp; %>
```